# pyspark: retrieve certain element in an iterable

Tags: apache-spark, iterator, pyspark, rdd

I am using the following code to iterate over the cogrouped elements:

```py
def find_animal(x):
    animal_list = x[0]
    tag_list = x[1]
    return animal_list[0] + "_" + tag_list[0]

spark_tag_rdd = spark_tag_df.rdd.map(lambda r:(r[1], r))

cogroup_rdd = spark_animal_df.rdd.map(lambda r:(r[1], r)).cogroup(spark_tag_rdd)
cogroup_rdd = cogroup_rdd.map(lambda r: find_animal(r[1])).flatMap(lambda r: r)
cogroup_rdd.take(5)
```

Then I got the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/spark-latest/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1306, in takeUpToNumLeft
  File "<ipython-input-23-b9a8d1714ae6>", line 4, in <lambda>
  File "<ipython-input-22-1d284bec23cf>", line 4, in find_animal
TypeError: 'ResultIterable' object does not support indexing
```

Basically I need to find the first element of an iterable, say we call it `current`. Then after a while, I want to find the next element after `current`. How to I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the input and expected output here?

Comment: Actually I just to find the first element of an iterable, call it current. Then after a while, I want to find the next element after current.